# Multiple users keys for the same repository

Tags: magento2, composer, auth.json

Hey guys I'm building a Magento 2 app where there are 2 different teams working on the project. 1 internally and the other outside of our premises and we have 2 separate Magento marketplace accounts. And we bought a plugin using our internal account but now we don't know how to have these 2 accounts in `auth.json`. We tried the following which our "outside" team but they say that it doesn't work:

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "",
            "password": ""
        },
        "repo.magento.com": {
            "username": "",
            "password": ""
        },
    }
}
```

Kinda makes sense why it doesn't work since we have two identical key names but still is there a way to do this in `auth.json`?

Answer (score 3):

This is a limitation of Composer, not Magento specifically.  There's actually an issue for Composer (https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/8724); your scenario is mentioned in comments created after the issue was closed.

The only option I'm aware of for sharing marketplace purchases is setting up shared access between the two accounts in question.  Once set up, the account that's granted shared access will be able to use marketplace purchases made on the account that has set up sharing.

The interface for enabling shared access is currently accessible from https://account.magento.com/grantor/manage/

There are more details in the dev docs: https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/magento/magento-account-share.html and a support article:https://marketplacesupport.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034703471-Transferring-Purchases-to-Different-Accounts-

Answer (score 0):

In this suitutation  you can fetch module from Private repositary insated of third party repositary.

- Copy module files in folder.
- Add path in composer.json.

> "repositories": {
> "unique_name_plugin": {
> "type": "path",
> "url": "private/repo/modulefoldername/Plugin"
> }
> },